# PHP skipping if blocks

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement

When I run this page, everything shows up correctly, but then when I try to test my various error messages, my button keeps redirecting me back to my login page as if everything was inputted correctly. It fails to register the if blocks I've included.  Below is the php (the html runs fine, not included).

*Side note, a few lines are commented out because I initially had PDO and am changing them over to mysql, but those shouldn't affect everything else running.  I have them commented out too so if things did work, I wasn't adding unnecessary info to my database.

Comment: Why would you change from `PDO` to `mysql`? You should do the exact opposite thing, change everything to `PDO` or at least `mysqli`.

Comment: *I initially had PDO and am changing them over to mysql* Wow that's a first. Please **don't** do that

Comment: Apart from that^ fact, why would you tag this question with PDO then?

Answer (score 4):

Of course, PHP is not skipping anything. It is diligently running your conditions, but in your code the only condition that affects the insert is the last one.

To make it work as desired you have to change all your ifs to `elseif` save for the first one

Answer (score 0):

The problem: Your error may be set, but your `INSERT` will execute only if `$password == $password2` which will be true if they're both empty.

You need to indicate alternative paths by doing `else if`

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL);

$error = "";

if (isset($_POST['createAccount'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $province = $_POST['province'];
    $postalCode = $_POST['postalCode'];

    if (!$username){
        $error = "<br><div><em>No username entered.</em></div>";
    }
    elseif (!$password || !$password2){
        $error = "<br><div><em>Missing password.</em></div>";
    }
    elseif (!$firstName || !$lastName){
        $error = "<br><div><em>Please enter first and last name.</em></div>";
    }
    elseif (!$address || !$city || !$province || !$postalCode){
        $error = "<br><div><em>Insufficient address provided. Please fill in all fields.</em></div>";
    }
    elseif ($password != $password2){
        $error = "<br><div><em>Passwords do not match.</em></div>";
    }       
    else{

        $conn = mysql_connect(<blocked out for privacy reasons>);
        $db = mysql_select_db("grocery", $conn);

        $account = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                                    FROM accounts 
                                    WHERE username = '$username'",
                                $conn);

        $rowExist = mysql_num_rows($account);

        if ($rowExist == 1){
            $error = "<br><div><em>Username already exists.</em></div>";
        }

        else {

            //$newAccount = ("INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, first_name, last_name, street, city, province, postal_code)
            //                  VALUES ('$username','$password','$firstName','$lastName','$address','$city','$province','$postal_code')");
            //$conn->exec($newAccount);

            header("location: GroceryLogin.php");
        }
        mysql_close($conn);
    }
}   

// I'm guessing here you do an echo $error;
```